# Add GPS metadata to UIImage when sharing with UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gps, uiimage, metadata

I am creating a UIImage in Swift from a UIColor chosen by a user, and I am hoping to attach some metadata to the image when it is saved or shared using the UIActivityViewController.  I am specifically looking to attach GPS coordinates to the image.  I see a lot of questions that look close, and references to the ImageIO framework, but most of these questions seem to be related to images selected from a UIImagePicker.  Here is my function for creating the image initially:

```
class func fromColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1080, height: 1080)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

I understand that the UIImage itself has no metadata attached, but is there a way to set the GPS metadata as the image is being saved to the roll or otherwise shared?  I am a relatively new dev, so trying to translate C code to Swift is a little over my head.